# Accessing clearcase view drive from virtual machine is slow

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, shared-folders

I have a windows XP virtual machine running under a Windows XP host.

On the host :

On the host clearcase 7.1.1.2 is installed. I have a dynamic view mapped onto some drive. The view has certain VOB/directory structure where my application DLLs from the nightly build and config files are stored. I run my application on the host machine which uses the DLLs and config files from the VOB and everything runs smooth.

Now I want to move this set-up to a virtual machine.

On the guest :

I'm running the guest with a vm-player.
I don't want to install clear-case on this as I don't want to expose this machine onto the network. The network setting in the guest is 'host-only'. I have mapped the host's clearcase view drive as a shared folder and I'm able to access this drive from the virtual machine. Also, the application is running.

However, the problem is that the access of the clearcase drive from the virtual machine is very slow. I can experience this from the windows explorer. Due to this, the starting of my application takes several seconds in the virtual machine while on the guest it comes up pretty fast.

My question is : Is there any way to speed up the performance? I have managed to copy some of the DLLs which don't change frequently to the virtual machine to improve the performance. However, there are still lot of DLLs which have to be taken from the clearcase drive as they change frequently.

VMplayer version is : VM Player 3.0.1 build-227600
Both guest and host is : Windows XP service pack 3
Host clearcase is : clearcase 7.1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to resolve this problem with a snapshot Clearcase view. The original view was a dynamic one and the DLL loading from this was unacceptably slow. After making a snapshot view and sharing the folder which stores this view contents with the virtual machine I managed to get a decent performance from my application hosted in the virtual machine.